# ReactJS - How can I correlate my data in td tags to move when th tag order is moved in my table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I am trying to move the correlated data in my CarTable.tsx component to move when the th tag's content changes. So if I click on the main button to shift my columns around I want to make the td tags to move when th tags are moved. So Car's Make data moves to the correct column where the header is 'Make', car's Year data moves to the correct column where the header is 'Year'.

I hope that makes sense...

Let me know if further clarification is needed.

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Car } from './Models/Car';
import CarTable from './CarTable';
import * as Bootstrap from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends React.Component<any, any> {

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cars: [],
      ordering: []
    }

    this.changeColumnOrder = this.changeColumnOrder.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let order = [
      ["Model", "Make", "Year"], ["Model", "Year", "Make"], 
      ["Make", "Model", "Year"], ["Make", "Year", "Model"], 
      ["Year", "Model", "Make"], ["Year", "Make", "Model"]
    ];

    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); // 0 - 5

    var models: string[] = ["Accord", "Civic", "Pathfinder"];
    var make: string = "Honda";
    var years: number[] = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019];

    var cars: Car[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
      var randYear = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); // 0 - 9
      var randModel = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // 0 - 2
      cars.push(new Car(models[randModel], make, years[randYear]));
    }

    this.setState({
      cars: cars,
      ordering: order[2]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>Car Table</h1>
          <Bootstrap.Button onClick={this.changeColumnOrder} className="columnButton btn-danger">Change Column Order</Bootstrap.Button>
          <CarTable cars={this.state.cars} order={this.state.ordering}></CarTable>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }

  // Method for changing the column order of the contents in the car table. 
  changeColumnOrder() {

    let order = [
      ["Model", "Make", "Year"], ["Model", "Year", "Make"], 
      ["Make", "Model", "Year"], ["Make", "Year", "Model"], 
      ["Year", "Model", "Make"], ["Year", "Make", "Model"]
    ];

    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); // 0 - 5

    console.log("Testing random order");
    console.log(order[random]);

    this.setState({
      ordering: order[random]
    });

    console.log("Testing after set state.");
    console.log(order[random]);
  }
}

export default App;
```

CarTable.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Car } from './Models/Car';

export default class CarTable extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return(
            <table id="carsTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    {this.props.order.map((column: string, key: any) => {
                        return(<th key={column}>{column}</th>)
                    })}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.cars.map((car: Car, key: any) => {
                        return(
                            <tr key={key}>
                                <td key={car.Make}>{car.Make}</td>
                                <td key={car.Model}>{car.Model}</td>
                                <td key={car.Year}>{car.Year}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a library which does the table manipulation and various other features. 
Check out ant design

Comment: What I have done is have an array of the column names I want and rearrange it as per need

Comment: Yes I have the column names and I can rearrange them on button click but the records don't move accordingly with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not reordered as `td` and `th` are not bound to each other in any way. Your `CarTable` component orders `th`s correctly, only a small change in the `tbody` is needed: do not use `car.X` directly, but follow the `order` fields, like this:

```js
{this.props.cars.map((car: Car, key: any) =>
    <tr key={key}>
        {this.props.order.map((column: string, key: any) =>
            <td key={column}>
                {car[column]}
            </td>
        )}
    </tr>
)}
```

Now each row is rendering its cells based on the given `order`.

Comment: I think I sort of understand what you trying to do. This doesn't work however. I also think you probably need two return statements since it is like a for each loop within another for each loop. Also I don't understand the car[column] syntax. 'car' is a single object with three properties on it, Make, Model, Year.

Comment: Can you explain _how_ it doesn't work? There are no `return` statements as that's how [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) work. The `car[column]` is getting the `column` property of the `car` object. In your case, either `Make`, `Model` or `Year`.

Comment: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Car'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Car'.ts(705

Comment: No, it's **not** a syntax error, but a TypeScript type error. In your case it's because `order` is not really `string[]` type, but `('Make' | 'Model' | 'Year')[]`, so `column: 'Make' | 'Model' | 'Year'` is the exact type you need.

Comment: I don't understand how you'd somehow associate column using array notation on an variable/item car (type: Car) that is an object. Not a collection.

Comment: In JavaScript, the `[]` operator is not only restricted to arrays, but also to objects. Consider this code: `const object = {a: 1, b: 2}; const key = 'a'; console.log(object[key], object['a'], object.a);`. All these three are equivalent.

Comment: I sort of understand now. But I still feel stuck fixing my problem. I had a different approach that I got to work by creating another component and passing in this.props.order[0], etc. And that child component conditionally returned which property to display. But I would still like to figure out how to use your approach here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's working. Can you ignore the type errors for a second and try it? If it's still not working, please describe how (what is happening, what's the error, etc.).

Comment: Nope, I keep getting that same Typescript error that I mentioned. Same message. The browser won't render the output, it displays that same error in the browser and in VS Code.

Comment: Actually I just got it to work by changing car from typescript type Car to any. It works!